# Clickable li but another li not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure this out, but for the life of me I'm confused. I have this:

```
<!-- Sidebar Menu -->
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="header">HEADER</li>
  <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
  <li class="active"><a href="res/link.php"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> 
    <span>Links</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i>
   <span>Multilevel</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul><!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
```

and my javascript:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.sidebar-menu li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-10)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('.sidebar-menu li a > .treeview li a').click(function(){
```

and I'm having trouble with this line:

```
$('.sidebar-menu li a > .treeview li a').click(function(){
```

I want the `sidebar-menu` menu clickable for all `li`'s with `a` tags however when I click on the `treeview` menu, it fires up as an href link. I don't want that clickable.

Am I using the greater than less than symbols correctly in my JavaScript?

Comment: In CSS (and thus also in jQuery), the `>` symbol indicates a direct child element.  So, `a > .treeview` selects elements with a class of treeview, whose parent element is an `<a>`.  Your HTML doesn't appear have any of that, so your click handler won't be bound to anything.  What did you think the `>` would do?

Comment: And if your HTML *did* have any elements that matched that selector it would be invalid, and the browser would - when creating the DOM - attempt to rearrange the element-nodes; and so the selector still wouldn't match.

Answer (score 2):

use this to prevent default href action

```
$(your selector).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // e for event
  // preventDefault will stop default href action
});
```

edit: or you can handle all # links with this selector and preventDefault

```
$('.sidebar-menu a[href="#"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

selector `a[href="#"]` will select only A-tags with param href == "#", then just use preventDefault() on them to stop default href action

Comment: @Yabo, you know you can insert an html/js/css snippet in your question, right?  same as jsfiddle, but works right in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only elements directly under your selector, use `>`.
This will select only `a` tags directly in the `li` tags that are directly in the `sidebar-menu`:

```
$('.sidebar-menu > li > a')
```

Your first onclick can look like this:

```
var href = $('.sidebar-menu > li > a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-10)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});
```

Your second one can just look like this:

```
$('.treeview li a').click(function(){
    // do stuff.
});
```

It depends on how much nesting you'll do, but this will apply to all `a` tags in your treeview, regardless of nesting level.

**EDIT**: 
I see you didn't want the tree clickable at all.  In that case, you shouldn't use the `a` tag at all.  Use something like a `span` with styling that makes it look like a link. Links (`a`) go somewhere. If you aren't going somewhere, don't use the `a`.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6njj7L9g/2/

snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         
 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
 var href = $('.sidebar-menu li a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-10)){
   var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
   $('#content').load(toLoad)
  }           
 });

 $('.sidebar-menu > li > a').click(function(){
          
  var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
  $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
  $('#load').remove();
  $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
  $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
  function loadContent() {
   $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
  }
  function showNewContent() {
   $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
  }
  function hideLoader() {
   $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
  }
  return false;
  
 });

});
```

```css
.treeLink{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sidebar Menu -->
<section>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="header">HEADER</li>
  <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
  <li class="active"><a href="res/link.php"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> 
    <span>Links</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i>
   <span>Multilevel</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><span class="treeLink">Link in level 2</span></li>
      <li><span class="treeLink">Link in level 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul><!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `href=""` and not `href="#"` if you don't want it to be click-able.